# Opening of Excel sheet once and writing on it iteratively

Tags: c#, excel, automation

my app in c# has a prob in writing to excel sheet.
My app create excel sheet for its purpose and  does not write in it.
the below code is for reference only..

```
class a
{
    void m()
    {
        b bee=new b();    
        Excel.Application oXL;
        Excel._Workbook oWB;
        b.write(oXL,oWB); //will be called multiple times
    }
}

class b
{
    static b() //declared static so that only once excel workbook with sheets will be     created
    {
        Excel._Application oXL = new Excel.Application();
        Excel._Workbook oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing));
    }

    write( Excel.Application oXL, Excel._Workbook oWB)
    {
        oXL.Visible = true; //Here its throwing, Object reference not set to an instance of an  
                    //Object
    }
}
```

Help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: @Akshata : Thanks for ur help, very new to SOF :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to have code along the lines of the following:

```
class a
{
    b bee;
    public a()
    {
        bee = new b();
    }

    void m()
    {
        b.write(oXL,oWB); //will be called multiple times
    }
}

class b
{
    public b()
    {
        Excel._Application oXL = new Excel.Application();
        Excel._Workbook oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing));
    }

    write()
    {
        oXL.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

You then need to make sure, that you create only as many instances of `a` as you want Excel sheets.

You can use it like this:

```
a aa = new a();
for(...)
    aa.m();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.. But class a will be called from another class multiple times!.. so thr are 3 classes invovled. So need to make constructor b() such  that it will be called only once even though the class b is called multiple times...

Comment: Let me give u a brief idea of my app. MyApp basically fetches data from a list box(contains list of XML file names selected by user) for processing and parses data to excel sheets. So I only create 2 excel sheets and all the files data will be put in only 2 sheets. prob is ,each time a file is fetched from listbox(foreach) a new excel sheet is created. So if 10 files are in listbox 10 seperate excel files will be created, which is not intended.

Comment: Not if you do it the way I told you. I told you to declare an instance of `a` before the loop and reuse it inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
void m()
{
   b bee=new b();    
   Excel.Application oXL; // not initialized here!
   Excel._Workbook oWB;   // not initialized here!
   b.write(oXL,oWB);      // calling with uninitialized values! 
}
```

// ...

```
class b
{
   static b() 
   {

       // here you declare two local variables not visible outside of your 
       // static constructor.
       Excel._Application oXL = new Excel.Application();
       Excel._Workbook oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing));
   }

   // oXL here is a parameter, meaning it is completely different from
   // the local oXL in your static constructor
   void write( Excel.Application oXL, Excel._Workbook oWB)
   {
        oXL.Visible = true; 
   }
 }
```

I think what you want is to declare oXL and oWB as member variables of class b. Try something like this:

```
void m()
{
   b bee=new b();    
   b.write();
}
```

// ...

```
public class b
{
   Excel._Application oXL;
   Excel._Workbook oWB;

   public b() 
   {

       oXL = new Excel.Application();
       oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing));
   }

   public void write()
   {
        // do something with cXL and oWB here
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, sorry I forgot to mention,I have 2 excel sheets rather, I had initialized before inside m(), but that was opening up excel sheet(which was not intended).So I need to open that up only when it enters write method inside class b, but parameters needs to be passed from m() from class a. how to go about that?

Comment: Omitting of parameters in write is throwing same exception as mentioned in the code.