# How to make constructors to be called only once even though the class is called multiple times?

Tags: c#, constructor

By default constructors will be called whenever class is called, how make it to be called only once without making use of static constructors?

Comment: By default constructors will be called whenever class is *INSTANTIATED*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A static constructor is only called once per class. An instance constructor is called every time an instance of the class is created.
To me, it's unclear why you can't use the static constructor.

Comment: @Daniel : because static constructor is not allowing me to access variables initialized inside of it.

Comment: @Srikanth: What do you want to achieve? A static constructor can't access instance variables, because they are specific to each instance of the class. It's clear that they can't be accessed from the static constructor. Your requirement makes no sense. Please describe the use case and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Daniel : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040708/opening-of-excel-sheet-once-and-writing-on-it-iteratively .. Please have a look into this .. ur Help is needed

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with this question

Comment: if u see in that Q i'm trying to write to a excel sheet iteratively, but the same excel sheet should be used for writing again and again which  i'm not able to achieve. As shown there if i use static constructor of class b, write method is not working(error is thrown); if I make constructor PUBLIC , each time different excel sheet opens up, which shouldn't happen...

Comment: Singleton pattern is your solution. Using it you'll have only one instance and can access instance members statically

Answer (score 1):

Use the singleton pattern.
Take a look at 
http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html